# Select grouped table from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables in MySQL.

excel - is the table where I store site-name, and side-id
analys_result - is the table where I store keywords of sites, it has keyword, id of the category, id of site.
categories - contain name and id of category

Here are screenshot's of tables, and what I need to retrieve:

Excel table
[image]

analys_result table
[image][image: Category]

Result
[image]

Comment: you didn't post the `categories` table. it's probably easier to do the formatting in php

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I add category table, i need to select data in format last picture, i try joins, group by, nested queries but that didnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just sql, the best you can get is:

```
select e.id, e.url, c.CategoryName, a.Keywords, count=sum(a.count)
from excel e, categories c, analys_results a
where e.id = a.websiteid
and a.categoryid = c.id
group by e.id, e.url, c.CategoryName, a.keywords
order by e.id, e.url, c.CategoryName, a.keywords
```

This will get you the correct data, but the grouping fields (id, url, categoryname) will show on every row in the result set  (not ONCE per group), and making the query work that way using complicated SQL is **NOT** recommended. Let the database give you the data, and let the UI or Reporting Tool you are using determine how you want to display the results.